# How to use DHCPClient by changing it to IPV6 android in aosp?

Tags: java, android, android-source, ipv6, inetaddress

I want to use only ipv6 through DHCPClient. When I analysed the code, I got to know that, the default IP address assigned by DHCP is typically IPV4. Let me know how to change by redirecting it to IPV6?

I am not able to find where exactly in [DHCP](http://aospxref.com/android-6.0.1_r9/xref/frameworks/base/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpClient.java) assigned it to IPV4

Let me know how to change by redirecting it to IPV6 address?

Log:

```
DhcpClient: Received packet: d4:53:83:c6:3d:25 ACK: your new IP /192.168.29.29, netmask /255.255.255.0, gateways [/192.168.29.1] DNS servers: /192.168.29.1 , lease time 3600
```